# How to convert a div into an image, without using html2canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with a bunch of elements that are transformed with CSS. This div needs to be converted to an image.

I've tried using html2canvas, but it doesn't support Transformed elements very well, so the exported image looks nothing like how the browser displays it. What's the best way to convert a div with styled elements to an image, without using html2canvas?

Styling that doesn't convert well with html2canvas:

```
transform:  perspective(100px) rotateY(10deg) rotateX(2deg) rotate(-11.5deg);
```

Comment: As far as I know there is sadly no other way than using a canvas. Maybe you can find another library instead of html2canvas.

Comment: if you bring up chromes devtool you can use a command like [capture node screenshot](https://umaar.com/dev-tips/156-element-screenshot/) but i guess that is not what you are after... To do it programatically you need to ask for permission to [capture the screen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API) and to capture a node you need to figure out where the position of the element are relative to the viewport and clip the screen and capture it to a canvas element. But if you use something like [puppeteer](http://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) then it's way easier

Comment: The same goes fore Firexox. If you click the triple dot after the URL bar, one of the options is screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Using [Phantom JS](https://phantomjs.org/) is not an answer here, since it will capturing the whole page, The best way here is [domtoimage](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) library to convert a div to an image.

**Script**

```
<script src="path/to/dom-to-image.min.js" />
<script>
var node = document.getElementById('my-node');

domtoimage.toPng(node)
.then(function (dataUrl) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = dataUrl;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The html2canvas library is used widely to capture web content directly from the browser. However, it may not be working very well with transformed elements.

As suggested by many, there is no other front end library which is know to be working well in your circumstances. (Did you try [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlshot) one?)

One other reliable way of doing this is getting the capture done in the server side. You can send the markup to the server, use a headless browser to render and get the image.

[Phantom JS](http://phantomjs.org/) is a good candidate for this and is based on Webkit. It is known to work well for most situations.

However, Phantom JS is not actively developed any more. But it maybe of good help in your case.

> ```
> var page = require('webpage').create();
> page.open('http://www.google.com', function() {
>     setTimeout(function() {
>         page.render('google.png');
>         phantom.exit();
>     }, 200);
> });
> ```